# How to split program up in c++

Tags: c++, oop

I'm getting into OOP now, but the files are becoming quite big. I was wondering if there was a way of putting some larger functions in separate files and the classes into a separate file too. For example, say I had the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

//------------------------SHAPE------------------------------------//

class shape {
    protected:
        double area;
    public:
        shape(): area(0) {}
        shape(double A): area(A) {}
        virtual ~shape() {}
};

//------------------------SQUARE------------------------------------//

class square : public shape {

    friend ostream & operator<<(ostream &os, const square &squ);

    protected:
        double width;
    public:
        square(): shape(0), width(0) {}
        square(double w): shape(w*w), width(w) {}
        virtual ~square() {}

};

ostream & operator<<(ostream &os, const square &squ) {
    os << "Width: " << squ.width << ", Area: " << squ.area;
    return os;
}

//------------------------CUBE-------------------------------------//

class cube : public square {

    friend ostream & operator<<(ostream &os, const cube &cub);

    public:
        cube(): square(0) {}
        cube(double w):
            square(w) {}
        cube(square squ):
            square(squ.getwidth()) {}
        ~cube() {}
        double volume() const {
            double temp = width*area;
            return temp;
        }

};
ostream & operator<<(ostream &os, const cube &cub) {
    os << "Width: " << cub.width << ", Volume: " << cub.volume();
    return os;
}

double square(double N) {
    return N*N;
}
//------------------------MAIN------------------------------------//

int main() {

    square s1;
    //other stuff

}
```

How would I put the classes in one file and the function in another and the main in another but still have it all compile with g++?

Comment: Are you using `g++` from command line, makefile, or IDE (such as Eclipse or CodeBlocks)?

Comment: What is your platform:  Windows, Cygwin or Linux or embedded?

Comment: The general convention is you put the class and function *declarations* in a header file, and the corresponding *definitions* in the cpp file. Then `#include` the header in the cpp file.

Comment: Hi, so I'm using Lubuntu 13.10 and writing the files on gedit, but compiling by running `g++ main.cpp -Wall` from the terminal. I'll also need to know how to do this using visual studio when I submit my final program since that's what my university uses.

Comment: Remove `using namespace std;`, that will shorten your file by one line (and really you should not be using this anyway).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, your declarations go into a .h file, and the definitions go into multiple .cpp files.

Each file that needs to know the structure of each of those classes needs to `#include` the .h file.

Since your `shape` class is well-structured already, it can be put into `shape.h` pretty much as-is.

Your `square` class, as it is derived from `shape`, needs to `#include "shape.h"` as well as a few of the other global includes, such as `#include <iostream>` since it's utilizing `ostream`.

Your `cube` class is actually mixing both declaration AND definition in some parts, which is better to be broken apart: `double volume() const` should only be declared in the `cube.h` file, and then actually defined in `cube.cpp` with:

```
double cube::volume() const {
    double temp = width*area;
    return temp;
}
```

When you actually go to compile, the typical way to do it is to compile them into object files, usually on the command line with `g++ -c -o cube.o cube.cpp cube.h shape.h`, where it creates a bunch of `.o` files.

Then once all those individual files are compiled into those `.o` segments, you combine them all and link them together: `g++ -o my_completed_project shape.o square.o cube.o`.

(There may be a few typos in this: this was all off the top of my head... sorry about that.)

But all-in-all, your code looks very clean to me. It's well-structured, and easy to read. Great work!

**EDIT:**

Typically, a declaration only gives the structure of the function, so the compiler knows that it will have a specific return type, the name of the function, and the type and number of arguments. The compiler doesn't know what that particular function *does*; it just wants to know that you're passing in what it's expecting, and that you expect a certain return type.

Declarations go into the .h files, and are very minimalistic: it tells nothing more than "what the function looks like."

Definitions, on the other hand, go into the .cpp files, and when you compile the program, it tells the program *what* to do once that function is called. The `cube.cpp` file now defines what the `volume()` function should **do** (it should return `width*area`).

However, since `cube` derives from the `square` class, during compile time, all it cares about is that there is a `getwidth()` function defined in `square`, that it takes no parameters, and that it returns a `double`. It doesn't care *how* it gets the value for that `double`: just the fact that it is declared in the `square.h` is good enough for the compiler to have all the information it needs to compile `cube.h` and `cube.cpp`.

Comment: Wow, thank you for your answer and also for the compliment. I've come from python really so one gets quite used to structuring code, that's my only explanation. Could I just ask for a some expansion on how one can tell if something is being 'declared' and if something is being 'defined'?

Comment: Edited my post. Hope it helps; and feel free to keep asking questions!